# Shift beamer onslides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I have a complicated "animation" in tikz which contains ~100 lines which have `<13-15>`, `<17->`, `<-5>` etc. after `\node`, `\draw` etc.

Now I wish to add a couple of extra slides with pauses *before* the animation begins. In other words, I would wish to encapsulate the tikzpicture in a "scope" which will start running after a couple of `\pause`'s.

Is that possible in beamer?

One workaround which I don't really like, but seems possible: add a new frame with all the texts that appear before the "animation" with no pauses and start the animation there from step 0. The problem with this workaround is that I will have to change the vertical alignment of the frames to `top` to avoid bouncy behaviour.

Comment: You can use \onslide<13-15>{\node...; \draw...;} instead of \node<13-15>...;

Comment: I know, but unfortunately, that is not too helpful in my case, as any `\node` etc. has a distinct slide number.